# How can get my oracle sqlplus querys into .sql file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I run queries in SQLPlus. Now I want to get all queries into .sql file. how can I do it? please help me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you save *all* of them, but - you can one by one. Use `save` command.

```
SQL> select empno, ename, job sal
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = 10;

     EMPNO ENAME      SAL
---------- ---------- ---------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT
      7934 MILLER     CLERK

SQL> save q1.sql replace
Wrote file q1.sql
```

Only query gets saved, not its result:

```
SQL> $type q1.sql
select empno, ename, job sal
from emp
where deptno = 10
/

SQL>
```

---

As you already closed SQL*Plus, check `v$sql`. In order to be able to use it, `sys` should grant you (i.e. the user which will query it) privilege to do so:

```
SQL> connect sys/pwd as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> grant select on v_$sql to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
```

You'd then *spool* result into a file:

```
SQL> spool q.sql
SQL> select sql_text
  2  from v$sql
  3  where to_date(first_load_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') >
  4        to_date('30.05.2020 20:50', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
  5    and parsing_schema_name = 'SCOTT';

SQL_TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select empno, ename, job sal from emp where deptno = 10

SQL> spool off
```

Comment: i already execute all the command and I closed the sqlplus. but now I need to get all the previous queries. is there any way to do that

Comment: Yes; query v$sql. I added an example; have a look, please.

Comment: @MadhushaniHewagama There is an option  `set history on`  but it's cleared as soon as you exit Sqlplus other option is to download [sqlcli](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html)  or GUI tool [SqlDeveloper](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sql-developer.html)